# AWS SNS/SQS - Prevent multiple subscription from a topic to a queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

So I'm subscribing SQS queues to SNS topics. As it seems you can subscribe the same topic to the same queue more than once and the result is that you receive the same message multiple times in the queue. Is there a way to prevent this kind of behavior, I only want one subscription from a topic to a queue.
I can't find anything addressing this behavior on the official documentation or anywhere else.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you find out anything about this? I see multiple subscription from my SQS to the same SNS topic, but i'm not sure if this is causing multiple delivery of the same message.

Comment: When I was working on this what I found out was that you will receive as many messages as subscriptions. Let's say if you have 3 subscriptions from the same topic to the same queue you will receive 3 messages when you send 1. I'm not working on this anymore but I remember that I somehow was creating 2 subscriptions instead of one for each queue to the same topic and that was causing the multiple delivery problem.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I came across the same problem. My problem was that I was playing with the topics and queues while learning and didn't actually know that if you remove a queue, topic, or both, the subscription will stay in the subscription list and will be displayed in the subscription list for a new queue with the same name.